# Retrieving large datasets using RIA services

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, ria

We are planning to develop a charting application based on Silverlight(using infragistics [xamdatagrid](http://community.infragistics.com/blogs/kiril_matev/archive/2010/06/23/using-the-xamdatachart-financial-indicators-and-overlays-in-your-technical-analysis-scenarios.aspx)). The application will be very much like Google Finance like charting tool with an ability to view historical data. We have a master table that has stock indicies and a bunch of other parameters for the last 20-25 years.

Is it wise to use RIA services to retrieve the data and render the data charts on a silverlight application? Also please note that the master table in the database may be subject to many changes(addition or removal of columns) and we would not like to always update the service/webapp to reflect the changes and therefore needed the design to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Hope not too much late, anyway I hope this answer could help others. I recommend for this scenario create a Data Warehouse to make the queries to create the charts against it and not against the real active and frequently changing source database.